# when i do distcp whether mapper will run in Source or destination

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, distcp

I am running a Distcp in hadoop  to load the data  from dev cluster to production cluster .. my question is from where the resources will take.. is it from  source or destination?

Answer (score 1):

Distcp spins off MapReduce jobs on the cluster it is running on/from. You can use the Yarn UI on that cluster to monitor the job progress and utilization.

Lets assume if you are copying from a Prod cluster to a Dev cluster, and are worried about resources utilization , then you can actually run the Distcp job on the Dev cluster and have it "pull" the data from Prod cluster.

Answer (score 1):

where ever you initiate the job/run the distCp command it will use the resources in that environment.

**Side note:** You can initiate the job in source or destination as long as you give the right source and destination.